# How to parse the Java source code in groovy?

Tags: java, parsing, groovy

Lets say I have java class:

```
public class A
{
    public void testMethod()
    {
        //some line
    }
}
```

how will I parse the above java code using groovy APIs? This is what I'm looking for, parse the class and get all method definition in the parsing class as [List of BlockStatement](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/stmt/BlockStatement.html), so that I can iterate over it and do some comparison.

How should I do that in groovy?

Comment: Use a Java parser library?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Yeah probably right, but I was thinking since groovy overs AST stuff at the language level, was feeling it should provide an easy way.

Comment: Don't forget that not all Java is parseable by the Groovy parser

Comment: @tim_yates Yeah thats fine. I just wanted to see how this can be done in groovy

Comment: @batman Groovy doesn't have facilities to do this.  You could write a Java parser in Groovy if you wanted, but one doesn't exist as far as I know.  Because you mentioned `BlockStatement` I wonder if you are confused about how the joint compiler works but to clarify, the Groovy compiler does not parse and compile Java source code. The Groovy compiler delegates that work out to the Java compiler.

Comment: @batman "I was thinking since groovy overs AST stuff at the language level, was feeling it should provide an easy way." - The Groovy compiler does not generate an AST for Java source code.